# Drag and drop MIDI files to Finder is working but not other applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and drop from a NSOutlineView in my application to other applications (.mid MIDI files), and it is working. I can drag them to Reaper (the DAW) into a track and I can drag it to the Finder. But when trying some other applications like Presonus Studio One it rejects it without showing the plus sign. If I drag the same file directly from the Finder to Studio One it's working, so Studio One is accepting the file, but just not from my application.

My code should work because it's possible to drag the file both to Finder and Reaper.

Why isn't this working? I'm so confused right now..

Here's my code:

```
// The interface
@interface OutlineViewController : NSObject <NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSDraggingDestination>...

@implementation OutlineViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        // I have tried to call this from awakeFromNib but no difference
        [self insertAll];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}


- (void) insertAll
{
    [_outlineView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LOCAL_REORDER_PASTEBOARD_TYPE, NSStringPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
    [_outlineView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:NO];
    [_outlineView setAutoresizesOutlineColumn:NO];

    // HERE it will insert all lines to the outline view and it is working...

}
- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{
    return !item?[_people count]:[[item child] count];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{
    return !item?YES:[[item child] count] != 0;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
{
    return !item?[_people objectAtIndex:index]:[[item child] objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
{
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
        return [item name];
    }
    else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"parentName"])
    {
        return [item parentName];
    }

 return @"";
}

- (id<NSPasteboardWriting>)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView pasteboardWriterForItem:(id)item
{

    // This is returning a valid NSUrl like
    //  file://localhost/Users/Me/File.mid on a drag
    // everything's working to Reaper and Finder
    return (id <NSPasteboardWriting>)[item fileURL];

}
```

Comment: shouldn't `[self inserAll];` be `[self insertAll];`

Comment: @l'L'l yes you are right it was a typo in the code here (sadly), I'll change it now. Thanks